Did Einstein say that space and time no longer existed as independent entities?
I was trying to locate the original quote by Einstein saying that space and time no longer existed as independent entities but they were replaced by spacetime. (Words to that effect)
I asked Google's Gemini and it gave a literal quote from Einstein's Meaning of Relativity. I searched the book  but I could not find such a quote.
There is a consensus that it was Minkowski who first declared the unification of space and time:

But Einstein didn’t go quite so far as to advocate joining space and
time into a single unified space-time. That step was left to his
former university professor, Hermann Minkowski, in the early 20th
century. The arena of special relativity is today known as Minkowski
space-time.

Apparently Einstein too said something similar but I could’t find that quote.
In Meaning of Relativity Einstein wrote:

In the pre-relativity physics space and time were separate entities.
Specifications of time were independent of the choice of the space of
reference.

This is close but it is not a direct assertion of the unification of space and time. Do you know if Einstein made such a statement? Thanks

Good ol' Google Gemini, still forging a source as if it couldn't read every book in the world.

Never trust an LLM for factual information

@Mauricio Not only an LLM, never trust any secondary source.

The crediting to Minkowski for the unification of space and time is very much Einstein's. For example in his:

Einstein, A. (1916). Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie, Annalen der Physik, 354: 769-822.

he write (English translation from A. Einstein Collected Papers Vol 6):

The generalization of the theory of relativity has been facilitated
considerably by Minkowski, a mathematician who was the first one to
recognize the formal equivalence of space coordinates and the time
coordinate, and utilized this in the construction of the theory.

(emphasis is mine)
There was a gradual evolution of Einstein's way of looking at special relativity via Minkowski developing a tensorial formulation of the same. Einstein eventually realized this to be a fruitful framework, and allowed the pathway to develop of general relativity in the framework of differential geometry.
The development of Einstein's perspectives on formulations of special relativity, Minkowski and the transition into general relativity is captured in:

Weinstein, G. (2012). Max Born, Albert Einstein and Hermann
Minkowski's Space-Time Formalism of Special Relativity. arXiv preprint arXiv:1210.6929.

Given this history Einstein's admiration for the particular mathematical formalism dates to 1912 but he would end up being a generous creditor to Minkowski for pointing the way (as seen above).
